# Помогите создать запрос SQL

Tags: php, mysql, sql

У меня есть 5 таблиц, в первых двух одинаковая структура, как и во вторых двух, а пятая таблица соединяется с каждой по общему столбцу. Мне необходимо получить данные из таблиц (Не склеить, а именно получить построчно), которые соответствуют id пользователя и соответствуют диапазону дат и после этого сортируются по дате по убыванию. Я уже бьюсь битый час над созданием запроса для склейки этих таблиц и общей сортировкой получившейся, но в итоге так и не нашел возможности выполнения данного запроса. Так же, хотел уточнить, полученные данные я буду выводить через PHP, и мне необходимо как то идентифицировать данные, из какой таблицы они были получены, могу ли я дополнительно добавить еще один столбец к получившимся запросам с идентификатором?
Помогите пожалуйста написать такой запрос, я буду примного благодарен.

Мне необходимо выбрать все данные из sales, orders, cancel, wb_return по диапазону дат и usr_id, и подцепить по общему полю nmId таблицу nomenclature_list, после чего отсортировать по столбцу date по убыванию

Вот сама структура таблиц (Извините, не умею делать таблицы из текста):

```
    -- phpMyAdmin SQL Dump
-- version 4.9.7
-- https://www.phpmyadmin.net/
--
-- Хост: localhost
-- Время создания: Сен 12 2023 г., 18:35
-- Версия сервера: 5.7.21-20-beget-5.7.21-20-1-log
-- Версия PHP: 5.6.40

SET SQL_MODE = "NO_AUTO_VALUE_ON_ZERO";
SET AUTOCOMMIT = 0;
START TRANSACTION;
SET time_zone = "+00:00";

--
-- База данных: `winzerpro_wb`
--

-- --------------------------------------------------------

--
-- Структура таблицы `cancel`
--
-- Создание: Сен 06 2023 г., 17:35
-- Последнее обновление: Сен 11 2023 г., 20:48
--

CREATE TABLE `cancel` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `usr_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `gNumber` varchar(51) NOT NULL,
  `date` varchar(32) NOT NULL,
  `lastChangeDate` varchar(32) NOT NULL,
  `supplierArticle` varchar(76) NOT NULL,
  `techSize` varchar(31) NOT NULL,
  `barcode` varchar(31) NOT NULL,
  `totalPrice` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `discountPercent` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `warehouseName` varchar(51) NOT NULL,
  `oblast` varchar(201) NOT NULL,
  `incomeID` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `odid` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `nmId` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `subject` varchar(51) NOT NULL,
  `category` varchar(51) NOT NULL,
  `brand` varchar(51) NOT NULL,
  `isCancel` tinyint(1) NOT NULL,
  `cancel_dt` varchar(32) NOT NULL,
  `sticker` varchar(128) NOT NULL,
  `srid` varchar(128) NOT NULL,
  `orderType` varchar(128) NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

-- --------------------------------------------------------

--
-- Структура таблицы `nomenclature_list`
--
-- Создание: Сен 06 2023 г., 17:35
-- Последнее обновление: Сен 12 2023 г., 08:32
--

CREATE TABLE `nomenclature_list` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `usr_id` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `sizes` varchar(4096) NOT NULL,
  `mediaFiles` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `colors` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `updateAt` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `vendorCode` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `brand` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `object` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `nmID` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `imtID` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `isProhibited` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `tags` varchar(255) NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

-- --------------------------------------------------------

--
-- Структура таблицы `orders`
--
-- Создание: Сен 06 2023 г., 17:35
-- Последнее обновление: Сен 12 2023 г., 08:38
--

CREATE TABLE `orders` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `usr_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `gNumber` varchar(51) NOT NULL,
  `date` varchar(32) NOT NULL,
  `lastChangeDate` varchar(32) NOT NULL,
  `supplierArticle` varchar(76) NOT NULL,
  `techSize` varchar(31) NOT NULL,
  `barcode` varchar(31) NOT NULL,
  `totalPrice` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `discountPercent` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `warehouseName` varchar(51) NOT NULL,
  `oblast` varchar(201) NOT NULL,
  `incomeID` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `odid` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `nmId` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `subject` varchar(51) NOT NULL,
  `category` varchar(51) NOT NULL,
  `brand` varchar(51) NOT NULL,
  `isCancel` tinyint(1) NOT NULL,
  `cancel_dt` varchar(32) NOT NULL,
  `sticker` varchar(128) NOT NULL,
  `srid` varchar(128) NOT NULL,
  `orderType` varchar(128) NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

-- --------------------------------------------------------

--
-- Структура таблицы `sales`
--
-- Создание: Сен 06 2023 г., 17:35
-- Последнее обновление: Сен 12 2023 г., 08:38
--

CREATE TABLE `sales` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `usr_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `gNumber` varchar(51) NOT NULL,
  `date` varchar(32) DEFAULT NULL,
  `lastChangeDate` varchar(32) DEFAULT NULL,
  `supplierArticle` varchar(76) DEFAULT NULL,
  `techSize` text,
  `barcode` text,
  `totalPrice` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `discountPercent` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `isSupply` tinyint(1) DEFAULT NULL,
  `isRealization` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `promoCodeDiscount` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `warehouseName` text,
  `countryName` text,
  `oblastOkrugName` text,
  `regionName` text,
  `incomeID` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `saleID` text,
  `odid` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `spp` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `forPay` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `finishedPrice` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `priceWithDisc` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `nmId` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `subject` text,
  `category` text,
  `brand` text,
  `isStorno` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `sticker` text,
  `srid` text
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

-- --------------------------------------------------------

--
-- Структура таблицы `wb_return`
--
-- Создание: Сен 06 2023 г., 17:35
-- Последнее обновление: Сен 12 2023 г., 08:38
--

CREATE TABLE `wb_return` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `usr_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `gNumber` varchar(51) NOT NULL,
  `date` varchar(32) DEFAULT NULL,
  `lastChangeDate` varchar(32) DEFAULT NULL,
  `supplierArticle` varchar(76) DEFAULT NULL,
  `techSize` text,
  `barcode` text,
  `totalPrice` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `discountPercent` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `isSupply` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `isRealization` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `promoCodeDiscount` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `warehouseName` text,
  `countryName` text,
  `oblastOkrugName` text,
  `regionName` text,
  `incomeID` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `saleID` text,
  `odid` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `spp` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `forPay` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `finishedPrice` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `priceWithDisc` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `nmId` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `subject` text,
  `category` text,
  `brand` text,
  `isStorno` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `sticker` text,
  `srid` text
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

--
-- Индексы сохранённых таблиц
--

--
-- Индексы таблицы `cancel`
--
ALTER TABLE `cancel`
  ADD PRIMARY KEY (`id`);

--
-- Индексы таблицы `nomenclature_list`
--
ALTER TABLE `nomenclature_list`
  ADD PRIMARY KEY (`id`);

--
-- Индексы таблицы `orders`
--
ALTER TABLE `orders`
  ADD PRIMARY KEY (`id`);

--
-- Индексы таблицы `sales`
--
ALTER TABLE `sales`
  ADD PRIMARY KEY (`id`);

--
-- Индексы таблицы `wb_return`
--
ALTER TABLE `wb_return`
  ADD PRIMARY KEY (`id`);

--
-- AUTO_INCREMENT для сохранённых таблиц
--

--
-- AUTO_INCREMENT для таблицы `cancel`
--
ALTER TABLE `cancel`
  MODIFY `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT;

--
-- AUTO_INCREMENT для таблицы `nomenclature_list`
--
ALTER TABLE `nomenclature_list`
  MODIFY `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT;

--
-- AUTO_INCREMENT для таблицы `orders`
--
ALTER TABLE `orders`
  MODIFY `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT;

--
-- AUTO_INCREMENT для таблицы `sales`
--
ALTER TABLE `sales`
  MODIFY `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT;

--
-- AUTO_INCREMENT для таблицы `wb_return`
--
ALTER TABLE `wb_return`
  MODIFY `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT;
COMMIT;
```

Comment: Добавьте в вопрос структуру таблиц и набор полей, который вы хотите вытащить.

Comment: Добрый день. Обновил описание и добавил таблицы

Comment: Если у тебя есть таблицы с одинаковыми столбцами - в 99.999% случаях ты  спроектировал БД __неправильно__.

Comment: В данном случае в разных таблицах хранятся заказы, продажи, возвраты и отмены. Почему неправильно?

Comment: Отмена - это статус заказа. Также как и возврат - статус продажи.

Comment: Это понятно, но даже если бы я сделал так, то у меня получилось бы 2 таблицы, которые необходимо было бы свести)

Comment: Ну так `JOIN`-то вроде изобрели.

Comment: Так JOIN присоединяет по общему принципу строку, а мне необходимо выбрать все данные, и к каждой строчке по JOIN'у присоединить данные

Comment: Мне кажется или вы действительно усложняете себе задачу пытаясь сделать костыль? Напишите View, который будет выводить необходимые для вас данные по запросу и далее обращайтесь именно к View.

Comment: жестко раскидывать по 4м таблицам - заказы, продажи, возвраты и отмены. Такое обычно решается 1 табличкой и статусом. Тогда бы сову на глобус натягивать не пришлось. Вместо огромнейшего запроса не думали отдельно получить таблички, объединить в массив и отсортировать?

Comment: Методом PHP думал делать 4 запроса и уже сортировать непосредственно на самом PHP, но я думал, что возможно правильнее было бы делать это SQL запросом и меньшими силами получать нужный результат. Похоже придется делать выбор в пользу PHP, в любом случае всем спасибо за участие :)
По поводу закидывания всего в одну таблицу, это было бы неправильно, у продаж и возвратов другие столбцы по сравнению с заказами и отменами.

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте данный SQL код, заменив название столбцов на свои.

```
SELECT 
    'sales' AS source_table,
    s.*, 
    nl.*
FROM 
    sales s
JOIN 
    nomenclature_list nl ON s.nmId = nl.id
WHERE 
    s.date BETWEEN 'начальная_дата' AND 'конечная_дата'
    AND s.usr_id = 'идентификатор_пользователя'
UNION ALL
SELECT 
    'orders' AS source_table,
    o.*, 
    nl.*
FROM 
    orders o
JOIN 
    nomenclature_list nl ON o.nmId = nl.id
WHERE 
    o.date BETWEEN 'начальная_дата' AND 'конечная_дата'
    AND o.usr_id = 'идентификатор_пользователя'
UNION ALL
SELECT 
    'cancel' AS source_table,
    c.*, 
    nl.*
FROM 
    cancel c
JOIN 
    nomenclature_list nl ON c.nmId = nl.id
WHERE 
    c.date BETWEEN 'начальная_дата' AND 'конечная_дата'
    AND c.usr_id = 'идентификатор_пользователя'
UNION ALL
SELECT 
    'wb_return' AS source_table,
    wbr.*, 
    nl.*
FROM 
    wb_return wbr
JOIN 
    nomenclature_list nl ON wbr.nmId = nl.id
WHERE 
    wbr.date BETWEEN 'начальная_дата' AND 'конечная_дата'
    AND wbr.usr_id = 'идентификатор_пользователя'
ORDER BY 
    date DESC;
```